# High Quality ComplexPlot

Tags: plotting

Using version 12.0.0.0, I am using ComplexPlot to create a figure. This example is from the ComplexPlot help page. I am using the command

```
g1 = ComplexPlot[(z^2 + 1)/(z^2 - 1), {z, -2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I}, 
  ColorFunction -> "CyclicLogAbsArg"]
```

and the figure I get looks something like this, cropped and zoomed in.

[image]

I expected the figure to be higher quality. All lines and edges look so rough so the graph looks very low quality. I want to export this, import this in latex, and print maybe a 6" x 6" version of this figure. The figure looks pretty bad even in MMA before I even attempt exporting it.

How can I make this plot higher quality with more detail?

I have tried the following

- MaxRecursion -> 4
- WorkingPrecision -> 100
- PerformanceGoal -> Quality (seems to make it better but the edges are still noticeably rough)
- PlotPoints -> 250

but I have only tried these individually and they seem to make no difference. I don't know enough about graphics in MMA to figure out which combination of these settings will work or if there is something else that I am missing. I would like to get a high quality PDF exported.

Comment: `RasterSize -> 1200`

Comment: `ComplexPlot[(z^2 + 1)/(z^2 - 1), {z, -2 - 2 I, 2 + 2 I}, 
 ColorFunction -> "CyclicLogAbsArg", PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
 PlotPoints -> 500, RasterSize -> 1000]` gives ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogIsd.png)

Comment: or `ImageSize -> 1500`